# creating .dump file

Tags: sqlite, dump

I want to create **.dump** file of sqlite database which include all the tables.   I created .sql file but I want .dump file. Also I created .dump file using **PRAGMA** function but it creates only single table.

```
.output output_file_name.dump
.pragma table_info 'table_name';
.dump table_name
.exit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#converting_an_entire_database_to_an_ascii_text_file) says:

> Use the ".dump" command to convert the entire contents of a database into a single ASCII text file.

So use the `.dump` command:

```
.output output_file_name.sql
.dump
.exit
```